# Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

I was playing music with my headphones plugged in. The music was coming out of the headphones, but I also noticed that my speakers were playing the same music.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/150959/61218) helped me to get rid of this problem. My card was an Intel card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound from both headphones and speakers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers)

Comment: This question is not localised. and could have perfectly good answers, but as others have said try the above answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably an alsa issue. I had the same problem, but it got reported as a bug and fixed.

[link to bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/477226)

Comment: +1: This is an ALSA bug.  In addition to whatever workaround you can get, please file it - our audio maintainer is pretty good with these :)

The driver needs to have a correct mapping of all the various inputs your sound hardware has - one of which is a “you've got headphones plugged in” signal - and not all systems have correct mappings.

Running “ubuntu-bug” should get you the symptoms-based reporter, where you can get the relevant audio logs to a bug.

Comment: It has worked for me since the upgrade to 10.10 on hda intel platforms.  the previous solution was to open sound preferences, which triggered a probe and changeover to headphones.  in my opinion, not a bug...tradeoff for speed increase by not polling the interface

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. It appears that the new kernel did not correctly detect the sound card model that you have. You will have to edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file and set the model manually with

```
options snd-hda-intel model=<model>
```

Unfortunately, finding the correct sound card model can take a little guess work. I took me several tries to find the sound card model that would detect the headphones correctly.

This link gives a list of sound card model:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568

More information can be found on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto).

Comment: If you have to do this, file a bug too; the kernel *should* detect the module automatically.