# HDA Intel ALC269VB internal mic only records a high-pitched whine

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

- The title pretty much says it all.
- See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/799058
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working/8211#8211) didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Henningsson suggested simply changing the input connector to "Internal Mic". That fixed it!

See [launchpad issue 799058](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/799058) for details.