# Any Fix for c720, Ubuntu 14.04, Internal microphone not working?

Tags: sound, microphone

I can't get my Internal mic working by default.
Only way how to get it work is open pavucontrol and choose - Microphone (Unplugged), only then it records sound from my Internal Mic.

This C720 is for my GF, and I don't think she will appreciate doing all this staff over and over agian in order to skype someone. I mean to Open terminal CTRL+ALT+T - pavucontrol - Go to Input devices and select Microphone (Unplugged).. all this just to Skype.
Is there more rational solution ?
I tried everything from [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working)

Including

> In terminal run:
>
> sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
>
> Add these two lines to the
> end of alsa-base.conf :
>
> alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
>
> options snd-hda-intel model=auto
>
> Save and reboot.

Thanks in advance. Valdis

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your alsa conf file instead:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=,alc283-chrome
```

https://github.com/eyecreate/ubuntu-chromebook-installer/blob/master/profiles/devices/acer-c720/system/etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf