# Internal mic is not working on my lenovo b50 series laptop with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, microphone

Internal microphone of my laptop is not working whereas when I connect earphones with mic, it works fine.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on lenovo b50 series laptop.

As per suggetion [Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working), I have installed "pulse audio volume control", it shows good sensitivity and input when I have plugged-in microphone under input devices tab. But, when I remove it the "*internal microphone*" shows very less input and "*microphone (unplugged)*" shows nothing at all in orange bar.

I also tried adding following lines in "*/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*" config file

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

But, no use. Could someone please help me? I usually have to have hangout chat with clients and I could not do it without one pin earphone (as there is only one slot available for external mic+speaker device)

Thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: Could anyone please help me here? I am still facing this issue :(  Should it be question for Lenovo guys? However, things are fine with windows OS

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem. Brand new Lenovo B50 and Ubuntu 15.10. I have tried all the solutions I could find in this forum and others but am not able to get my microphone to work in Skype or Hangouts.