# Asus X540S laptop microphone not working

Tags: asus

I have a new Asus X540S and the mic is not working.

It's enable in sound/input, is not mute. I try this:

[Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working)

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 5):

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
hdajackretask
```

Then: Show unconnected pins, override pin 0x12 to internal mic. Install boot override.

It worked in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: why exactly 0x12?

Comment: this worked. It only needs (after the setting) to ensure that the mic level is  high enough in sound settings (pavucontrol, etc)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/358741/32012

Comment: I had to tweak the exact settings but this got me on the right path, +1

Comment: I'm having the same internal mic problem on my ASUS and started doing this but there is no pin 0x12 listed. There is another pin listed as being the mic...so do I do that to that one even if it's not pin 0x12?

Comment: Can confirm this works, Ubuntu 20.04 Asus UX425EA

Answer (score 0):

Edit this configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=laptop-dmic
```

Comment: Do I need to restart anything after?

Comment: Didn't help, is the index supposed to be the soundcard #?