# Microphone is not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have problem with my HDA Intel PCH audio under Ubuntu 16.04. I never had any problem with speakers, however my microphone is not working.

When I plug microphone in jack, system reacts and it looks like microphone is in, however no single bar appear in any settings in "Input levels". The microphone works fine, just tested on notebook with Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: Screenshot]

[Here is my info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e7ff1d41121e5c8be7f9ea1f005e741524b48178)

Comment: did you solve your problem ?? im having the same issue!

Answer (score 18):

I had this exact problem. My solution:

1) open PulseAudio control

2)go to the configuration tab.

3)select analog stereo duplex to use the computers built in audio&mic

[image]

Comment: I've found that even though my setting was Analog Stereo Duplex, switching to another setting and then back to duplex solves the problem.

Comment: anyway to make it switch to microfone automatically? This one works but seems we have to change the output manually everytime

Comment: This did not fix it for me

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this will work. Please reply to see if this is specific to that laptop or not.

https://askubuntu.com/a/824806/47206

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358989/32012

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Then launch

```
hdajackretask
```

Then:

Check 'Show unconnected pins'

Check override pin 0x12 to internal mic.

Apply and test. Be sure that the mic level is high enough in sound 
settings (pavucontrol, etc)

If it worked 'Install boot override'.

[image]

Comment: im having the same problem and this answed didnt solve it ?? any other solutions

Comment: @ForDev -  what laptop do you have? Do you see your mic in audio settings or in `pavucontrol` under *Input Devices* tab? If not,  under *Configuration* tab: be sure you have selected ''Analog Stereo Duplex".

Comment: thnx for replay i have just switched to debian and everything is working fine thnx :) i try all the solutions but didnt work for me i think the problem mybe comes from the updates because before everything was working fine

Comment: @ForDev - you mean this was fixed with Debian rolling? What kernel version please? Maybe I'll stumble into this in the future on that Asus and using a newer kernel may be the way to go.

Comment: When I try to apply changes I get this error: pa_stream_writablee_size() failed: Connection terminated

Answer (score 7):

My issue was a small variation to OP's problem - I have a headset (combined stereo headphones and mic) jack.

First use hdajackretask check that the problem is not related to the jack (eg see [user47206's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/904654/553502)). For me, my jack was correctly detected as 'Headphone'.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to access the terminal.
2. Type `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` in the terminal and take note of the codecs listed.
3. If there are multiple codecs listed, determine which one relates to your headset jack. For me there were two listed - one related the the video card (`Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI`) and another related to the sound card (`Codec: Realtek ALC3861`). In my case, I was interested in the sound card because I was connecting to the PC headset jack and not a HDMI device such as a PC monitor.
4. Look up the HD-Audio model for your codec in [HD-Audio Codec-Specific Models](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html). For my headset jack, the best fit was the *dell-headset-multi* model.
5. Type `cd /etc/modprobe.d/` in the terminal.
6. Type `sudo cp alsa-base.conf alsa-base.conf.bak` to backup the file before editing.
7. Type `gksudo gedit ./alsa-base.conf` to edit the file.
8. Insert this line at the bottom of the file `options snd-hda-intel model={HD-Audio model for you codec}`. For example, for it me it was `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi`.
9. Save file and reboot.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me (aspire-headset-mic model).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, though I can see it makes a  difference.  The appropriate choices for my model seem to be alc662-headset or alc662-headset-multi.  If I use these, then plugging in the headset gives me a Headphone/Headset/Microphone window selection, but the microphone on the headset still doesn't work, and in fact the headphones don't work either now!  If I try dell-headset-multi, then the microphone works but the headphones don't.  I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: @CharlesRezk I also have that problem sometimes. Restarting Pulse Audio (eg `pulseaudio -k`) usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I did it guys!

1. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Look for the `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` and change it to
    `options snd-usb-audio index=0`
3. Add `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

Comment: unfortunately this did not work on ubuntu 19.1 + acer swift 3 :(  looks like this was my last option.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and tried every answer I found online with no luck. Finally, from alsamixer I changed the Channel option which was 6ch, to 4ch or 2ch, and the mic started capturing input, don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

Very easy solution.

[image: Screenshot]

tl;dr : press red volume icon as shown in screenshot image above.

I had the same problem. On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, KDE

My solution:

1) Go to "Audio Volume Settings"

2) Select "Input Devices" (Tab)

** in the top right corner the sound icon is marked in red. As mute.

3) Press (left click) the red sound Icon (mentioned above)

4) Press OK

Check if problem is solved.

If not make sure to choose the right option from the port options in the Input Devices Tab (I choose Internal Microphone) and make sure the volume percentage is above 0%, preferably for the test set to 100%.

It was the internal microphone on my laptop. Meaning the built-in mic in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Context: My headset audio was fine and the internal mic was also working. The only problem was with the headset microphone. It was not detecting. After the following steps, it worked again.

Few steps I tried:

1. Open the `HDAJackRetask` application. You need to install it if you have not.
2. Choose different codecs and choose `Show unconnected pins`.

   [image]

3. In pin ID: 0x18, click override, and select Headphone from the dropdown.
4. Click Apply now and Install boot override.
5. Hit `sudo also force-reload` in the terminal.
6. Restart your PC.
7. Now again open the `HDAJackRetask` application and toggle the override option for pin ID: 0x18 to off.
8. Click Apply now and Install boot override.
   It worked after this step. If not, try restarting the computer.

I cannot assure it will work for everyone though. :)