# Front headphone jack not being recognized

Tags: 16.04, alsa, music, headphones

So my front headphone jack in not being recognized and I'm forced to use the one from the back which works fine.

Ubuntu 16.04

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=122fcab05365bf73501cc46c960ef99b50ac3924

also here is a screenshot after running `alsamixer`

[alsamixer picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zIZs.png)

Comment: From your `alsamixer` picture, it seems your headphone is muted (`MM` shown in the bottom). Try to unmute by pressing `m` on the keyboard; should then show `00` in green color like with the other channels.

Comment: I presses "M", it has now 00 and I crank the volume up but still no sound

Comment: Next step: Run `pavucontrol`(the pulseaudio mixer) and look what output device is selected for the program in use (`Playback`tab), what output devices are available (`Output Devices`tab) and how they are configured (`Configuration` tab). Play around a bit to see what options you have.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. My solution:

1) open PulseAudio control

2)go to the configuration tab.

3)select analog stereo duplex to use the computers built in audio&mic.

Reference from question answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895397/microphone-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04/966558#966558).

It may help. Worked for me.