# pulseaudio: Failed to find a working profile

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

**Note that: this is not duplicate**

After I power on my laptop and try to play some music I faced up with "Dummy Output" and I do some search and tried some famous solution and none of those worked for me, anyone can help me with this?

[image]

Os: `Ubuntu 20.04`

Kernel: `5.4.0-42-generic`

Also, I tried all solutions from

- https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/
- [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Dummy output, no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099053/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dummy-output-no-sound)

and none of the solutions worked for me.

When I run this command `pacmd list-cards` I get this:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CGss74Dt4n/

and the output of `pulseaudio -vvv` is: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/JN2vz4Pq8Z/

the output of `sudo play -l` is: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/X3M23w6b4d/

the output of `alsamixer` is:

[image]

Comment: You can try running `pulseaudio -vvv` and see if more detailed messages come up.

Comment: Also `lspci | grep -i audio` should reveal one or more PCI audio cards.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks for your comment, this is the output of `pulseaudio -vvv` : https://pastebin.pl/view/10367b9d

Comment: and this is the output of `lspci | grep -i audio` => `00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
`

Comment: My output is identical to yours except mine is `(rev 31)`. Can you boot into windows and update all your firmware drivers?

Comment: actually, I do not very know these things, can I boot into windows from the virtual box and do the update? is this is the only way to fix this :(?

Comment: I'm not even sure updating drivers will fix it. Lets wait and see if someone posts an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know if it's related to the problem or not,  but after trying any way to solve the problem, none of them worked, but after force shutdown, the problem was fixed and it's working properly now

**UPDATE March 2022:**

This issue happened to me again, I was watching a course and suddenly my laptop rebooted and after that, just dummy output showed to me and there is no sound.

**Solved:**
I purge all PulseAudio by `sudo apt purge pulseaudio*` and hard shutdown and installed it again and hard shutdown, weird! but it worked.