# How do I reinstall Ubuntu without losing data?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

Yesterday I did a system upgrade by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade` on my laptop,  a **Lenovo G50-80** which only runs `ubuntu 16.04` as my operating system of choice.

Everything from thereon went crazy, in a sense that my internal microphone could no longer work and the problem is that I discovered that while being interviewed using the [zoom](https://zoom.us/) application as it so happened that I could hear my interviewer but they could not hear me(which was gut-wrenching, to say the least).

I tried all solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895397/microphone-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) and many other solutions from other blogs and none of them worked for me.

This morning I turn my machine and I cannot seem to access my system settings and so my frustrations continue.

Anyway below is a screenshot of how I partitioned my hard drive
[image]

and I would like to know if I can reinstall my os(which will hopefully fix the microphone issue among others) on `/dev/sda1` without affecting the data on `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5` or do I have to backup all the data on these drives before doing that.

Thank you.

Comment: I would boot a 'live' (Ubuntu install media) and confirm your hardware all works as you believe it should.  If this is good, you can re-install Ubuntu using 'something-else' and not-format your partitions, which will take note of your software, erase system directories, install the system, add back your additional software without touching data (as long as you don't format) - but you should backup first anyway.

Comment: Also note:  if your problem is a global setting, or a system-file problem a re-install (without cleaning your $HOME or user directory) should fix the issue.  If however your problem is a setting in your own configs (ie. something saved in your home user directory such in ~/.config/), my prior comment's re-install suggestion without format may not fix the issue as your user configuration files (with problems) will likely still exist on your newly installed system.

Comment: Running a `dist-upgrade` without reviewing the proposed changes (which might be extensive) is unwise. The dist-upgrade output and prompts are there to protect you from precisely this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to do it since you have a seperate /home partition. This [tutorial](https://jerel.co/blog/2010/08/reinstalling-ubuntu-with-separate-home-partition-without-losing-data-tutorial-with-screenshots) should be of help. As always make sure you backup your important data things can go wrong.  Back up to the cloud or external media. Good Luck.