# SOLVED: Audio input not working, "...does not have capture controls" - new 18.04 install

Tags: gnome, sound, microphone, input-devices

*EDIT: I tried buying a USB Audio Card (USB Audio Adapter); it ouputs audio fine, but still no luck getting audio input. Interestingly, though, when I plug in my headset into the microphone jack I do get some bars in Sound > Input indicating it is receiving something. Additionally, in AlsaMixer if I switch sound cards to USB Audio Device and then go to 'capture device', I do see a Mic with a EQ bar above it that I can adjust, with CAPTURE in red text just below the EQ bar*

Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. No audio input from onboard mic or headphone/mic combo (these both work fine when I boot same machine, Acer Swift 3 SF314-54, via Windows 10), alsamixer showing "sound device has no capture controls".

I don't know if it's related, but I installed "Pulse Audio Shortcuts" extension and when I try to turn it on in the extensions section of the GNOME Tweaks program I see a yellow warning triangle with "Error loading extension" next to it. I don't appear to have gstreamer-properties command, either, even though I believe PulseAudio comes with 18.04?

Anyways, would be very grateful for approaches to solve this, thanks!

Here's my input and output settings:

```
~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC256 Alt Analog [ALC256 Alt Analog]
Subdevices: 2/2
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Subdevice #1: subdevice #1

~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[ALSA settings screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz5gyp6bokzt2s3/alsa-issue-0_delete_.png?dl=0)

[ALSA "no capture device setting" screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs5w08w54n6caq2/alsa-issue-1_delete_.png?dl=0)

Here's some related threads [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895397/microphone-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748274/asus-x540s-laptop-microphone-not-working/824806#824806) [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working) [[4]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358741/asus-x540s-laptop-internal-microphone-listed-but-not-working/358989#358989); I've tried basically all of the solutions suggested therein, except—as there were a number of different suggestions for how to modify `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`—I've only tried a couple of these but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the USB Audio Adapter ([examples](https://www.amazon.com/usb-audio-adapter/s?page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ausb%20audio%20adapter)) plus using a headset with a 3.5mm splitter.