# Ubuntu 16.04 - Internal microphone not working - Ideapad 310

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

My built-in microphone is not working properly on the programs I've tested it with like Google Chrome (Hangouts), Skype. But when I execute `pactl load-module module-loopback` I get the feedback **perfectly**.

Google Chrome (Hangouts) does not receive any audio. Skype receives but outputs a very low and buzzing sound.

I changed `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to add `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` and `options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad` but that did not work ([Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working/8211#8211)).

I am using Xubuntu 16.04.

[My ALSA Info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d26bc657f286b380d5facf45b0573f68117524ad)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

My Lenovo G70-80 built-in microphone was not working. I followed this [ubuntu wiki help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2FMicrophone_Troubleshooting).

Under **Increasing very low microphone input**, point 5, **Switch one of the input channels off** solved my problem. This notebook has only one mono microphone so one channel should be switched off. It's not important which - left or right.

> 1. Go to Input Devices tab and ensure you have the Internal Audio Analog Stereo or just Internal Audio Analog displayed by selecting All
>      input devices from the Display drop-down list.
> 2. Find the appropriate input device (microphone) and ensure its not muted - by unticking mute audio icon.
> 3. Unlock channels so that they are not linked together - by pressing a padlock icon or chainlink icon. Slide the slider of Front Right all
>      the way down to zero.
> 4. Talk to the microphone observing input level on the bar just below the two sliders or at the Input tab of Gnome-volume-control.
> 5. This should work when either channel is muted, though it is suggested to start with Front Right one.

Comment: After short time it is not working again.  I set volume for microphone in pavucontrol for instance to 75%, but when I started talking in Skype it is set to very low value about 10%.

Comment: This really worked! In order to make use of the answer, people should really follow the link. Otherwise it's hard to understand the box, because the instructions are all about `pavucontrol`.

Comment: I install new version of Skype 5.4.0.1, but no improvement. When I test microphone with Pulse Audio Volume Control it works - volume control does not change it's value. I guess, that Skype controls microphone wrong. And I cannot find in Skype some option to inhibit it.

Comment: Finally this did the Job. May the gods be with you...

Comment: This worked for me. I had a problem with using Google Meet within Google Chrome but however I have a problem. The recipients of the call told me that there is too much noise and static at their end whenever I speak. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

On my Lenovo Ideapad 310 and Skype I had to:

1. Open pavucontrol (install it if missing with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`)
2. Call someone or to Echo / Sound Test service (important step :) )
3. Go to the **Recording** tab; you will see something like "Chrome input"
4. In the **Recording** tab, unlock channels so that they are not linked together - by pressing a padlock icon or chainlink icon. Slide the slider of **Front Right** all the way down to zero.

Thanks to this - even after restart mic was working properly.

Comment: I had already tried to select the correct input device with the sound control in KDE's control panel (AFAIK from KMix) but it did not work. With `pavucontrol` I could actually see the input level and select the correct input device with the correct input stream.

Answer (score 4):

Yup! I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.10, where it was working perfectly on Skype but didn't work for chrome.

So I solved the problem just by reducing the **Front Right** slider under **Input Devices** on PulseAudio Volume Control.

[image: Volume Control settings, Front Right slider all the way down]