# Internal microphone does not work until an external one is plugged and then unplugged

Tags: sound, headphones, microphone

I have a problem with my internal microphone on ubuntu 19.04 (on an ASUS ROG laptop using NVIDIA gtx GPU ). It used to work well. I had a couple of meeting using this system earlier. But now it does not work. I tried almost every method available online([method 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878308/ubuntu-16-04-internal-microphone-not-working-ideapad-310/995406) [method 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working) [method 3](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/internal-or-external-microphone-not-working/8690/11)) . It did not fix the problem. I have been being harassing by ubuntu for quite a while. Once in a while, it pops up a different problem, then I spent hours and hours looking up online to find a solution.

Now the problem is the internal microphone. It does not work but it can be activated by external headphone with a microphone.  After a cold boot, the internal microphone does not work, after plugging in external headphone and removing it very quickly, then the internal microphone would function well.

Could you please give any help on how to fix it? A second question, should I update my ubuntu system at all? I am really tired of ubuntu problem and want it to stay at a functional status. But I have to stay with it because many coding and program can be done on Ubuntu much easier.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You say you have tried almost every method online, can you detail or list what methods you have tried?

Comment: @ Kristopher Thanks for your help. I listed the methods I tried in my post. I tried many suggestions in each post. One obvious hint to solve my problem is that my internal microphone can be activated by plugging in an external headphone then removing it quickly.

Comment: @ Kristopher Ives, every time when I boost the system, there are two input devices listed, the internal microphone - built-in audio and headset microphone, but none of them work. Once I insert the headphone jet and remove it quickly after plugging in, then there is just an internal microphone - built-in audio left in the list and it starts to work well. After reboot, it does not work again.