# Built-in mic does not work in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, pavucontrol

**Problem:**
The built-in microphone does not work (sound recording, Skype, Video conferencing apps, etc.).
Although all the apps recognize the built-in microphone as "Built-in analog stereo", none of them can actually get any sound from it.
The microphone worked before on Kubuntu 15.04 and under Windows 7.
The interesting thing is that when I open the Sound settings and go to the 'Input' tab, I can see that the "Internal microphone" does not hear my voice, but it does hear a loud hand clap.

**What I have tried:**

- Checked that the mic is not muted in sound settings.
- Changed the "Input volume" to over 100% in "Sound settings > Input".
- Changed the "Input volume" to over 100% in PulseAudio volume control (Input Devices).
- [Unlocked and muted one channel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working) with `pavucontrol`.

**Hardware/software:**

- Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E330 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- `uname -r` 4.10.0-27-generic
- MATE Desktop Environment 1.12.1
- `aplay -l`

  `**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
    Subdevices: 0/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`
- `dmesg | egrep -i "sound|audio|snd"`

`9.393579] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[    9.408050] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VC: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    9.408053] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    9.408054] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    9.408055] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    9.408056] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    9.408058] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[    9.408059] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    9.428090] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    9.434521] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    9.434570] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    9.434614] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10`

- `lspci | grep -i audio`

`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)`

Answer (score 0):

Not good having Pulseaudio levels above 100%, likely to cause audio distortion

Try checking ALSA level settings

`alsamixer -c 0 --view capture`

use spacebar to set capture for recording device

mic boost and capture level settings can be adjusted with arrow keys

Or use command:

`amixer -c 0`

for text output if you need more help finding settings