# Thinkpad T450 Ubuntu 18.04 - internal camera and microphone not working

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, microphone

on my Thinkpad T450 I set up a new Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

Unfortunately the build-in microphone and camera are not detected / working right now.

I tried editing alsa-base.conf like suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/204099/935144).
I also tried lowering the volume of one microphone-channel via pavucontrol.

The thing is that I have fn-shortcuts on my keyboard. They are all working (brightness, volume, etc..), but I don't get any reaction on pressing the shortcuts for toggling microphone or camera.

Do you guys have any idea what the reason could be or how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution ?