# Internal microphone not showing up on Lenovo Yoga S740-14IIL (18.04)

Tags: sound, lenovo, microphone

I followed the advice options here: [Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/6993/1063831)

[image: pavucontrol settings]

`tail /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

---

but I'm not even seeing a microphone in my settings:

[image: input settings]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the same laptop, running Debian and kernel 5.7 and below.

I have not managed to fix the problem, but as a workaround, if I plug in specific headphones (ones with a four-connector TRRS plug), the built-in microphone is mysteriously detected and can be selected as an input device.

Edit: With kernel 5.8 and Sound Open Framework 1.5.1 (https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin) the built-in mic is picked up without any messing around plugging things in.

Comment: interesting. if I plug in a TRRS heafphone/microphone, the Built-in Output is removed (and the Built-in input still isn't detected)