# Internal Microphone not detected in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone, pavucontrol

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04. on my Acer Swift SF314-57. Ubuntu does not recognize my built in microphone. The microphone works just fine in Windows 10.

I had problems with the sound card after ubuntu installation as ubuntu did not show it and respectively only dummy output in my sound output options. I fixed this by editing 
`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` adding `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`. The sound output works fine now. If I connect a headset, sound and microphone both work. However, the built in microphone is not detected.

My alsamixer output looks like this
[image: My alsamixer output looks like this]

I am a total noob and I am trying my best to get ubuntu to work smoothly. I would greatly appreciate some help on this matter.

So far I tried:

- editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and adding either  `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro enable=1 index=0` or `alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel` & `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` or all three of them (described here: [Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working))
- `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and unlocking the channels as also described in the link above. But I am not sure I fully understand what I have to do here. The end result of what I have done in pavucontrol looks like this
  [image]

I don't knwo what else I could try.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @M.A.K I have also same issue and I tried all thing can you tell me how you solved that