# Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo Ideapad Microphone not working

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio, 20.04, alsa, hardware

Internal Microphone is only recording static noise on Lenovo Ideapad and Ubuntu 20.04.
I've tried deleting PulseAudio config, restarting PulseAudio, and reinstalling Alsa. `sudo pavucontrol` was no help either. 
I know the mic is fine since it works on another OS.

This is the Alsa config:

```
pouria@pouria-pc:~$ sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

This is my hardware:

```
pouria@pouria-pc:~$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [17aa:380d]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
```

I just upgraded my kernel but didn't have any effect

```
pouria@pouria-pc:~$ uname -r
5.7.0-050700-generic
```

**UPDATE**:

I asked the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245434/ubuntu-20-04-fresh-installation-microphone-not-working) with no details (nor bounties), surprisingly some guy answered that gave me a clue.
[image: vokoscreen Alsa records fine]
In vokoscreen if I set the recording option to `Pulse` it doesn't record anything but when the recording option is set to `Alsa` it recrods.

So now I know **Alsa** is fine but **PulseAudio** is messing it up.
Now please help me with PulseAudio.

Comment: I'd be happy if you'd share how I can improve this question, or add more details to the problem.

Comment: What is your hardware? Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the tip, I edited the question and added the output.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253793

Comment: Well it looks like the device is not yet properly supported by linux. This happens. Vendors release new chips and don't send infromation to Linux. Maybe newest kernels have better support.

Comment: Try to install the 5.7 kenel. There is a good chance it will work.

Comment: @Pilot6 just did that, had no effect.

Comment: When you aren't using your microphone having the static along with tape over webcam could be a good anti-spyware defense.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm sure our brothers at Ubuntu software development had this in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally Solved: After I knew the problem was due to PulseAudio not Alsa I went to the [PulseAudio Troubleshooting page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Static_noise_in_microphone_recording) and I was amazed, they had a section on static noise, even mentioning my laptop name and model, also a section on microphone distortion. So I followed the instructions and it's now fixed.

**The Steps to fix the issue are:**

- In `pavucontrol` for my laptop model set left mic channel to zero.
- Edit `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input*.conf` and set mic boost volume to zero.
- I also added some noise reduction arguments from the same page.

Comment: Thanks. I could also use the slider in pauvucontrol to adjust the volume.

Comment: Thanks! In my case only the first step is enough - "In pavucontrol set left mic channel to zero".

Comment: This fixed only the distortion for thinkpad p52 by adding load-module module-remap-source source_name=record_mono master=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo master_channel_map=front-right channel_map=mono
set-default-source record_mono    to /etc/pulse/default.pa file. Seeking a way to fix the noise as all my volume boosts are already off

Comment: What do you mean "set left mic channel to zero"? Do you mean go to "Input Devices", find your mic, click "Lock channels together" and set "Front Left" to "Silent"? How do you "set mic boost volume to zero"? The word "boost" does not appear in that config file.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can check out the following post: [Disable PulseAudio Auto Volume](https://nzeid.net/pulseaudio-disable-auto-volume).

This post indicates that you can edit the following files as root:

```
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-dock-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-front-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-headphone-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-headset-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-internal-mic-always.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-internal-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-mic.conf
sudo emacs -nw /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-rear-mic.conf
```

And update the following fields wherever you see them in these files. You don't need to update volume if it's set to off. Only devices that are awake need to be adjusted.

- Under [`Element Internal Mic Boost]` set `volume`  to `zero`. This includes any variations like `[Element Dock Mic Boost]`.
- Under `[Element Int Mic Boost]` set `volume`  to `zero`.
- Under `[Element Mic Boost]` set `volume`  to `zero`.

Restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Dude this is step 2 of the accepted answer. Anyways, I give you the bounty 'cause don't want it to go waste and you seem cool!

Comment: Thanks for bounty. The link does have a little flair than Arch Linux link you posted.

Comment: the Arch Linux has the rest of the steps too, this step alone wouldn't fix the problem since left and right mic channel are canceling each other out. And by the way, I hate all distros of Linux equally.

Answer (score 2):

After a long try I found the solution for my Ubuntu 20.0.4 on my Lenovo laptop (Ideapad 330):

1. First delete the following files:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/
   ```
2. Then, Log out and Log back in.
3. Go to **Desktop Settings** and then **Sound**
4. Insert headphones and go to **Input** section.
5. Do microphone audio test on each available device.

Mic will start working.

Comment: My mic doesn't work. Not showing any volume.