# Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installation Microphone not working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, alsa, hardware, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the microphone is not working. It is recording only static noise.

Comment: Actually the answer here helped me more than the detailed question, so your decision to close this question is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Install pavucontrol: `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
- Run it: `pavucontrol`
- Open **Input Devices** tab and check if it is not muted

[image]

- Install `vokoscreen` recorder: `sudo apt install vokoscreen`
- Go to ***Microphone*** tab, enable **Audio**, check your recording audio device and try to record something with it

[image]

On vokoscreen's tab you have two options: Pulse and Alsa. Try if you could use either of them for audio recording.

To check if your microphone is working, use the next commands:

to enable microphone listening

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=2
```

to disable microphone listening

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

You could also run `alsamixer` and check if your **Mic** is not muted and has at least half of its volume. Use **F6** keyboard button to switch to other audio adapter if you have more than one.

Comment: Thank you man, in the vokoscreen I see that Alsa can record the audio, but Pulse can't, so this is definitely a problem with pulse audio.

Comment: Can you answer this now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243768/ubuntu-20-04-microphone-not-working

Comment: ty, this solved my problem.

Comment: I have been already testing it in skype. What do you mean by "try to enable your microphone listening " ?

Comment: I hear a _terrible_ noise (

Comment: @VictorVosMottor I had the same issue when microphone on my headphones had contact related issues. This way you could try to fix your microphone by moving it to change contacts position. Maybe it could help. Then just do not change its position.