# Built-in mic not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, microphone

I use a Lenovo laptop and in the setting of Ubuntu and I don't see any reading of the mic but the speakers are working and I tried many ways but still not working.

If solved, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245434/ubuntu-20-04-fresh-installation-microphone-not-working) solution. This might fix

Comment: thanks my mic is working but the discord app is not picking it up and also it's not showing reading in the sound tab of the mic section of the setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No microphone input on Acer Aspire One and Lenovo Ideapad 310-15ISK/330-15ARR**

Install pavucontrol, unlink the microphone channels and turn down the left one to 0.

Some applications (e.g. chromium) can change microphone levels causing the same issue, a workaround is to remap stereo input to mono and use the remapped device as default.

**Another Possible Cause**

Another possible cause is that your mic has two channels but only one channel can provide a valid sound signal. The solution is to remap the stereo input to a mono input:

1. Find your source name from the following command; `mine is alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`

   ```
    pacmd list-sources | grep 'name:.*input'
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add the following lines, where INPUT_NAME is name of the input source from above step:

   ```
   load-module module-remap-source source_name=record_mono master=INPUT_NAME master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono
   set-default-source record_mono
   ```
3. Restart PulseAudio:

   ```
   $ pulseaudio -k
   $ pulseaudio --start
   ```

Now `record` hopefully works. You may still need to change the `RecordStream` from setting to `Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Stereo` of a specific application in the `Recording` tab of `pavucontrol`.

for reference check this out:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Another_Possible_Cause

Comment: Thanks! Remapping solved mic issue in Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 310-15IKB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the pulseaudio configuration files:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/
```

Then log out and log back in, or reboot

The source for this solution is [this article](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04/) which states that it worked on Ubuntu Cinnamon 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked on my Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G3 ACL with Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and remove the `#` from the following line:

   ```
   #set-default-source input
   ```
2. Then execute the following commands:

   ```
   pulseaudio -k
   pulseaudio --start
   ```