# Microphone records only static/white noise

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, microphone, ideapad

My laptop's built-in microphone records nothing but static/white noise. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and my laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad 320. Any suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: Do you have any other operating system in your computer? Does the microphone work with that? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1274163/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo Ideapad Microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243768/ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-ideapad-microphone-not-working)

Comment: @Pizza, Yes, this does answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: Here's the exact answer that helped: https://askubuntu.com/a/1246455/1125500

Comment: @BlueCannonBall good note! As this still seems to be a common problem, if you stumble upon a similar question - make sure to flag it as duplicate to the same question i flagged so other users will be aware of a possible solution. Such specific questions sometimes tend to be missed and remain unanswered.