# Internal Mic not working properly

Tags: 20.04, acer, microphone

My internal microphone is not working as expected. It is detected in Settings -> Sound, as well as in pavucontrol. However, the captured mic audio seems to be at a very low volume, and only a slight static noise can be heard when i move the mic volume slider rapidly.

What might be the cause for this problem?