# Would anyone know why when I plug my headphones in, my speakers don't turn off?

Tags: sound, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

any ideas, thoughts or suggestions

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your sound card isn't known to Ubuntu, or needs a tweak ("quirk") in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

For example, Dell laptops often need `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-dmic` to be added to the end of the file.

Look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568) as a starting point for your model.

This is probably a duplicate of [Question 100](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in).

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer

In it's GUI interface there are several "PIN" options, if you click around "OUT" connector, you are able to forcefully turn on/off headphone and speaker configuration. That was the only solution what worked for me even with 2.6.36 kernel (I have Panasonic CF-R9).