# Headphone Jack has no sense

Tags: sound, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

How can I mute the speakers when the headphones are plugged in?

I have searched all over the internet and although there are many threads that discuss this, none has worked for me.

I have tried alsamixer and installing linux-backports-modules-alsa-lucid-generic, but neither worked. The Speakers just wont mute when I plug in the headphones. I had this problem in 11.04 and hoped it would be one of the headaches to go away when I downgraded to Lucid Lynx.

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC665
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
```

Model Name: [Alienware M14xR1](http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-m14x/pd.aspx) (PS: I am not a gamer so I have no attachment to Windows :) )

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    $ sudo lshw -c sound
       *-multimedia            
           description: Audio device
           product: Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 1b
           bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
           version: 05
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
           configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
           resources: irq:50 memory:da800000-da803fff
```

Comment: please add to your question `lspci | grep -i audio` and `sudo lshw -c sound` - can you confirm that you are now using lucid?

Comment: @fossfreedom I confirm that I am using Lucid. I have added the results in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)? There are a million ways of wiring these audio chips, so can you please add the model name of your laptop? Also have a look at [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/477226/comments/60). You need to find the right model, maybe [this list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto) helps.

Lucid is a year older than your Sandy Bridge laptop, so I guess it would be better if you install 11.04 or wait two months and install 11.10.

Comment: Alienware M14xR1. Added in the question.

Comment: Natty had a gazillion other problems, plus I hated Unity. It also appeared to me that classic Gnome was not high on the priority list for the devlopers at the moment, so I just deleted and reinstalled Lucid. I am also waiting for October.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could automatically do this but while you are waiting for a permanent solution assigning `amixer sset Speaker toggle` to a keyboard shortcut should help you.

- To do this open **system -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts**
- Click on **add**
- Give it a name and paste the above command
- Assign a shortcut to the command.

---

You could also turn your speakers off from the sound menu

- In the **sound menu** go to **output**
- In the drop down menu (**connectors**) select speakers
- Click on the **mute** checkbox