# Repair and consulting service for home-users?

Tags: system, canonical

I have a new Laptop on which I installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (dual boot with preinstalled Windows 7) since about a month. However there are three consistent problems that I have not been able to get rid of, no matter where I look on the internet. The primary reason is that it is difficult to explain and diagnose such problems when one of many things might be the issue.

Since I am sadly not an expert (yet), I would like to have some linux junkie have a look at my system and fix my problems. The problem is, I do not have a Linux Users Group that is active in my vicinity. I hardly know any expert. So are there such services or people that look into such problems at affordable rates? (My problems are: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56492/headphone-jack-has-no-sense), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56702/booting-to-no-display) (which regularly occurs now) and a slow + erratic wifi connection which becomes smooth and fast in Win7)

Or is it in the spirit of Linux to find a problem, learn about it, and fix it?

Comment: There is [canonical](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/desktop) at $105/desktop, which is decent, but I think they're targeted to businesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found Canonical's Ubuntu Desktop Service useful last year.  Friendly, prompt response.

http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/desktop

Currently $105/ year

Comment: This might be the one for me. What kind of problems did you face and were they completely solved?

Comment: We traced a bug, confirmed it was documented (HDMI out not supported on an old Dell netbook).  I discontinued after a year, because I have 7 machines running Ubuntu, and while their service was friendly and knowledgeable, and their web tool for managing systems was really nice (https://landscape.canonical.com ), the cost was prohibitive for me for multiple machine support.  This may have changed.

Comment: gare, one more question. what level of expertise does canonical expect of you?