# Sound from both speakers and headphones. Bug with Soundcard? 

Tags: 11.10, headphones, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

I just wanted to listen some music on my Notebook (Ubuntu 11.10), so I connected Headphones, and started Banshee. But later noticed the sound really came out of my headphones *and* my speakers.

I tried to fix it with Audio options, but I couldn't way and it isn't a Banshee bug.
I'm using a Medion *MD 96630*, [here's a chart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in) with its stats and it has a HDA-Intel-Chip with Realtek ALC888 Codec

Thanks to anyone who can answer me this, and please give me a detailed tutorial how to fix this.

Comment: Can you have a look on your Sound Settings > Hardware > Current Profile? What is selected there?

Answer (score 2):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=806620

This is an alsa issue with hda intel soundchips. There is a fix for it in the link above.