# headphones and speakers, both working

Tags: headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

as I am listening the song from my laptop, installed ubuntu 10.04 recently, and when I plugged in the headphones, the sound is still coming from the laptop speakers, creating noise. Please help me that how can I fix it?? there is no hardware problem coz when I was using windows, my headfones and laptop speakers were working perfectly well, separate from each other.

Comment: The answers in this question might help you:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in

Answer (score 0):

When you say working perfectly, I don't quite understand. Having the audio working from both sounds like it is working perfectly. You can control the volume of either the headphones or speakers separately from the volume control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Are your headphones plugged into the right plug? Or are they damaged in any way (plug might be bent, a wire might be loose at the plug, etc). Also, what headphones and sound card do you have?