# Headphones are plugged in and sound still comes out of Speakers

Tags: sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

I have an Asus K60IJ laptop, I am new to linux and was forced to come to linux when my windows os crashed on me and the reinstall disks would not work, Every time I plug in my headphones I have sound coming from my speakers as well, I messed with sound settings under output I see Analog Output and Analog Headphones seems no matter what one I pick sound comes from both.

I also installed Gnome-Alsa Mixer and Alsamixergui and Pulse audio control as well as Pulse audio mixer and pulse audio volume control, I have messed with all of them and none of them will fix the issue or give me a run around on manipulating the sound card.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10x32

Please can someone help me? I ask in irc but everyone ignores me for some reason and if they do help they are not successful.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Doug. There are many duplicate questions like yours, examples [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77817/headphones-and-speakers-both-working) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88756/unable-to-choose-between-speakers-and-headphones). Have you read any of these? The answer is probably there. If you try these and still have problems, post a new, more specific question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-sound-still-coming-from-speakers-after-plug-in-headphones-on-ubuntu-10-04) you can check a button called "Headphone jack sense" in gnome-alsamixer that should fix the problem. The same can be done through alsamixer by going over to "Headphone" and hitting the 'M' key.

Also have a look at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/886809) bug report. The OP says he solved it from a link on the report.

The bug report tells one way to do it, but the easier way is through the actual PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
```

Comment: http://imagebin.org/198681 , http://imagebin.org/198682

Comment: imagebin.org/198681 , imagebin.org/198682   under alsamixer in terminal its greyed out and i can not turn it up or down

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dkms-hda

Comment: all of them but the last one did not go, said unable to locate the package

Comment: Sorry about that, looks like the package name was a bit off: sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms

Comment: I used to know how to restart ALSA on-the-fly, but looks like they've changed it since the last time I had issues. Once you're done installing do a restart and hopefully it'll work! Well, since it loads kernel modules you'll have to restart anyway. I do hope this works for you.

Comment: ok done, now what do i do?

Comment: will reboot now and let you know, thank you for all your help

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the "E: Unable to locate package alsa-hda-dkms". any help?

Comment: Looks like the package was renamed to dkms-hda