# Ubuntu on Asus EeePc VX6s?

Tags: asus, eeepc

Does Ubuntu 11.10 works on Asus EeePC VX6s? Does all of the features work or what doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [Ubuntu Wiki's hardware support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Asus_VX6_Lamborghini):

> Asus VX6 Lamborghini
>
> Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Remix
>
> Works great. Havent tested everything but most day-to-day required things worked out of >the box. The Broadcom STA wireless driver, and NVIDIA driver, required proprietary >drivers, but these were easily installed through System>Administration>Additional >Drivers. 720p Video works fine with ffmpeg, havent setup vdpau yet.
>
> Audio output through headphones hasnt worked out of the box (havent tried fixing). >Havent tried bluetooth, hibernate, microphone, or HDMI out.
>
> Install Tip: no need to change BIOS. Insert thumbdrive (with Ubuntu install), press ESC >many times during boot, then select USB.

As far as headphones are concerned, upon installing you might follow the advice I gave [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103832/headphones-are-plugged-in-and-sound-still-comes-out-of-speakers/103839#103839).