# Sound from headphones and speakers (in ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: sound, headphones

not sure what changed, but when I upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 my laptop (acer aspire 3050)  started to get problems with my headphones.

now when I put headphones in is that the sound comes out of both the headphones and the laptop speakers, and that sound levels reset to maximum when I restart the laptop.

I can turn off the speakers using alsamixer.

I have also tried changing the settings in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf but no joy so far.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/100/7163

Comment: not sure this is a duplicate, i have tried all of the acer options in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Answer (score 1):

I had no sound coming through my headphones until I switched the output to Analog Speakers. Now it's fine.