# Sound coming out of speakers and headphones on an Asus K50AB

Tags: sound, headphones, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

I have ASUS K50AB with Ubuntu 11.10. When i plug in headphones, sound is coming out of the speakers as well. I cant solve this for long time and I tried lot of stuff that i find on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also own the ASUS K50AB, updated to 12.04 and this problem goes away. There is also auto jack sensing, so plugging in the headphones turn off the internal speakers. Try it out.