# Speakers / headphones always play simultaneously on an ASUS K50AB

Tags: sound, alsa, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

There is a major problem that I've been having with Ubuntu. I cannot play sound only on the speakers or only on the headphones. They always play simultaneously. I cannot control the volume for them independently.

I've tried many solutions found on the web including adding an 'options ...' line in some file (that seems to work only on Intel chipsets). I've tried updating the driver but the repository is not found and so on...

Could you please tell me if there is any specific solution related to my existing hardware?

Comment: Have  you tried going to Sound > Sound Preferences and changing settings on the Output tab?

Comment: Try this solution and the wiki page: http://askubuntu.com/a/216/235

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)