# Unable to choose between speakers and headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

everyone..

My PC has two audio 3.5mm audio outputs:
**back** - used for speaker system & **front** - used for headset

I want to know whether is there something in Ubuntu 11.04 that makes it possible to switch between speakers and headphones as and when required.I mean,avoiding audio playing out of both simultaneously and only out 1 of these 2.
After some Googling,I did the following

I.I installed  *padevchooser* but could not configure it do so.

II.Also installed *sudo apt-get install gnome-media* but still no difference was seen.

But after these steps,I connected my headphones and lessened the speakers volume and to my surprise,only the headphones were playing audio but the speakers did play audio along with the headphones if the volume was restored back to normal.

Has my problem been solved and if not,then whats the way to go about it?