# Headphone and built in speaker working together in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, 12.04, headphones, speakers, audio-jack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

If I connect my head phone to my laptop it doesn't stop my laptop built in speaker. Headphone works properly but at the same time laptop speakers also plays.

It supposed to stop as soon as I connect my headphone to my laptop which is not happening. And when I will remove my headphone from my laptop the sound should immediately go to my laptop front speaker.

Comment: File a jack-sense bug with alsa

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,

Comment: Hi, I've reported a bug on this but not getting any help. Please help me I'm in problem---> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/995684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double Sound Audio Microphone 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=831102

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.