# Sound comes from both headphones and laptop speakers

Tags: sound, 12.04, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound comes out of my speakers even when headphones are plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in)

When I plug my headphones into the headphone jack and start watching video or listening to a song, not only does the sound come from headphones, but also from the laptop speakers. This is annoying. What's the fix?

Answer (score 1):

it is your sound configuration
i had the same problem and this worked for me. sadly i dont remember how to get the available configurations. but you can try a few simple changes like auto

-in the terminal box insert. " sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf "

-enter password

-scroll down to the bottom of the page and insert the following command after the last command already there. " options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode3 "

-this one worked for me but you could try one of the other models ("asus-mode1" through "asus-mode8", or either "base" or "auto")

-exit saving your changes by holding down the "Ctrl" and "Shift" keys and pressing the " ^ " key (6) and than the "x" key.

-it'll ask you if you want to save your changes press "y" and than "Enter" to save the changes to the document.

-you'll find your self back in the terminal box. Now reboot your computer.