# Want sound only to headphones, when it plugged in, and in speakers else

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones, aspire

I installed 12.04 today.
It worked on 11.10.

Now if headphones was plugged in on startup, they works, but if I unplug it, speakers don't work.
If headphones wasn't plugged before startup, sound is in speakers and in headphones at the same time.

Laptop is Acer aspire 5930.

Card: HDA Intel
Chip: Nvidia MCP77/78 HDMI

```
riad@riad-laptop:~$ cat /proc/asound/pcm 
00-00: ALC888 Analog : ALC888 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-01: ALC888 Digital : ALC888 Digital : playback 1
00-02: ALC888 Analog : ALC888 Analog : capture 1
00-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
```

Same problem in 12.10dev

Which additional info should I provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ALC1200 and ALC888 seem to be very similar (see this [German Wiki Entry](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Soundkarten_konfigurieren/HDA?redirect=no#Beispielkonfigurationen)) you can try my solution for the Intel HDA ALC1200 on my Acer Aspire 5920 G laptop.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin from 11.10 my speakers continued to output the sound when plugging in headphones. In 11.10 the speakers were muted automatically when a headphone was plugged in.

I fixed it by adding a line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf :

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto probe_mask=1`

Now I've got a lot more options/controls when running `alsamixer`.
One is "Auto-Mute Mode". Set this to "Enabled" if it does not work out of the box.

stehpan

Answer (score 1):

Have paid attention for the same problem few minutes ago on my Acer 5920 (Intel HDA ALC1200),
and [**hda-jack-retask** utility that I've found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/128829/63365) seems to have solved my problem.
There are some comments about working ALC888 too.