# Headphone jack does not cut speakers in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, headphones, speakers

When I connecting my headphones to laptop, the speakers is still working. Where is the problem?

Comment: if this is an intel audio - this Q&A will help.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in

Comment: Everyone: Please note that Ask Ubuntu is not like ubuntuforums.org, when you post an answer, please post it as an answer, not an "This affects me too" post.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please report a bug and make your comment on the bellow link for permanent solution??

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/995684

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a hardware problem, not related to Ubuntu (to me, at least). In most cases, the headphone connector is designed in such a ways that inserting a headphone jack cuts of the signal that goes to speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, always worked perfectly until I dist-upgrade'd to 12.04. Have a Acer Aspire8930. Pluging in headphones works, I don't get sound through headphones. However, like described earlier in this thread, the speakers in the laptop are still making noise.
Cutting the volume using the volume in Ubuntu causes the headphones to be cut off also.

Only way to cut the speakers is to open a console and run `alsamixer`. Then fiddle around turning centre / side / surround and LFE down. The alsamixer doesn't work like before with me though, as sometimes sliders are turned up while I'm moving up or down a completely other slider. Seems like the sound system in 12.04 is kinda bugged for some setups / hardware.